# Regex goes wrong - which characters need escaping?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to extract an RTMP link from a website and has so far managed to find the line where it's located:

```
string line = GetLine(innerHTML, "turbo:");

// The string line now contains something like this:
// turbo: 'rtmp://fcs21-1.somewebsite.com/reflect/2996910732;0',

Match match = Regex.Match(line, @"turbo: '(rtmp://[*]+);0',$",
   RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

string key;
if (match.Success)
   key = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

There aren't any matches. What I would like to extract from this line:

```
turbo: 'rtmp://fcs21-1.somewebsite.com/reflect/2996910732;0',
```

is this piece:

```
rtmp://fcs21-1.somewebsite.com/reflect/2996910732
```

What am I missing in the Regex?

Comment: What data are you _really_ scraping? .NET has some _amazing_ HTML processing libraries like CsQuery that can eat properties from HTML and stuff like that really fast - you rarely actually need RegEx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your character class - `[*]` matches just a `*`, with quantifier `+`, it matches 1 or more `*`, nothing else. Clearly it won't match your string.

I guess you meant to use `.*` instead, which matches 0 or more occurrences of any character but `\n`.

Try changing your regex to:

```
"turbo: '(rtmp://.*);0',$"
```

or even better, given your text, and what you want to extract, you can simply use:

```
"turbo: '([^;]*);0',$
```

Answer (score 1):

`[*]` matches only `*`. To match any character, prefer `.`. (Re

(actually, `.` fails to match a newline. If a newline may appear, prefer something to the effect of `(.|\n)` -- note that the backslash will need to be escaped.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(line, @"^turbo: '(rtmp://[^;]+);0',$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

This will take into account the start of the string with the `^` symbol, and the matching selection will match anything that isn't a `;` all the way up to an actual `;`.